# Using harry potter in my Statement of Purpose

Tags: graduate-admissions

Can I use an occurrence in Harry Potter as a simile in my Statement of Purpose? I'm applying to an Ivy League university.

Comment: Please give an example of what you're suggesting.

Comment: It all depends on context. I mentioned eating gelato in my NSF Graduate Fellowship application and Ivy League PhD application and got both, but it was a very short remark and certainly not the core of any thread of the SoP. (I'm in pure maths).

Comment: Maybe in terms of bravery or over coming fears I guess.

Answer (score 19):

**Can** you use it? Absolutely—you have the freedom to write whatever you choose in a statement of purpose.

**Should** you use it? Almost certainly not, unless your research topic has something to do with literature. Otherwise, you run the risk of confusing the reader (who may have no knowledge of the books or movies), unless the reference is extremely obvious, in which case it will probably come across as clichéd and stilted.

Comment: ... and childish.

Comment: @paulgarrett Why childish? Maybe childlike?

Comment: aeismail, maybe the harry potter series gave h self-respect or helped h battle depression or something?

Comment: @Jack, I mean that, although some might perceive it as "childlike", many would perceive it as "childish", and it'd be undesirable to give that part of the audience a reason to react negatively. One is entitled to "stand on principle", more generally, but other peoples' reactions may not be as desired, etc. If the primary goal is eliciting a certain response ("hire me"), some risks are ill-advised.

Answer (score 14):

In addition to the risk of confusing or annoying the reader, keep in mind that a statement of purpose needs to show, with evidence, your interest and preparation for graduate study.   I don't know what you have in mind, but I can't imagine how a Harry Potter reference could contribute to that.  Writing something like "I'm better at physics than Hermione is at Potions", while it might be impressive if true, isn't helpful to your application unless you provide evidence of just how good at physics you are.  Anyone can claim to be great, and most applicants will, so you have to show it is actually true: what, specifically, have you actually accomplished?

And if you have the evidence, then the reference to Hermione is superfluous; save the space for evidence of your other great qualities.

Comment: On the other hand, "I'm better at physics than Hermione is at Potions" sounds like a good line for the world's nerdiest rap battle.

Comment: Nate, I think a better comparison is physics vs astronomy, chemistry vs potions or math vs arithmancy but then again, it's hard to be better than the best :P http://harrypotter.answers.wikia.com/wiki/Hermione's_OWL_grades